# Missing Polybase enable configuration on SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, polybase

I installed SQL Server 2017 Enterprise (14.0.3162.1) on my box. With the polybase (Scale-out Group). But when I try to enable through:

```
exec sp_configure @configname = 'polybase enabled', @configvalue = 1;
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
```

It shows:

> ```
> Msg 15123, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_configure, Line 62 [Batch Start Line 0]
> The configuration option 'polybase enabled' does not exist, or it may be an advanced option.
> ```

So I used:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced option', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE
Go
```

and check by:

```
select * from sys.configurations where name like '%poly%'
```

only:

```
polybase network encryption
allow polybase export
```

shows up.

How can I enable this feature in this case?

Please let me know if I missed any.

Comment: I'm not sure whether [this post](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/davidbenoit/configuring-polybase-cluster) helps.

Comment: @DBALUKE HUANG , Did you find any resolution to this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

SQL 2017 is not good with Polybase. Currently, I am using SQL 2019 for this and all is good.

Answer (score 0):

```
exec sp_configure @configname = 'allow polybase export', @configvalue = 1;
RECONFIGURE;
```